# Displaying mysqli usernames as correct case

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a simple member table that when output in php on a page, is always showing as lowercase.

The member names are not all lowercase letters in mysqli, but when I use

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>
```

they always show up as lowercase letters..

Here is some of the code I am using.

```
<?php
session_start(); 
require "config.php"; 
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){ 
} 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
   $user  = $_POST['user']; 
   $pass  = $_POST['pass']; 

   $user  = stripslashes($user); 
   $pass  = stripslashes($pass); 
   $user  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $user);
   $pass  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $pass);  
}
?>

$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$user'") or die("Can not query the TABLE!"); 
$add = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO members (id, username, password) VALUES (null, '$user' , '$pass') ") or die("Can't Insert! ");
```

Comment: So, which case do you want? Upper? Mixed? Weird?

Comment: I want it to show the same way as it is entered when someone signs up, which is the same way it shows up in mysqli

Comment: How are you setting `$_SESSION['username']`? Could you add the code that does that?

Comment: That will depend on how the inserts were originally done. What you posted will not affect lettercase.

Comment: I have updated with the insert

Comment: Can you add a few examples of what you have for usernames that were entered? Plus, have you tried them where one was mixed case entered by a user and one that is uppercase? I can't see how sessions would do this, unless the HTML form contains JS or something else that is changing lettercase. There's something you're probably not showing us.

Comment: I have tried one with all caps, and one just as mine is here. KJThaDon.

I just removed any css/js from the page, and still have the problem